What is the purpose of a communication cable in an instrumentation cable for installation?
Some cable manufactures opt to include a single/pair of insulated conductors with different colour blue/orange additionally in an instrumentation cable in order to facilitate the installation.
What is the purpose of these insulated cables?  How can they help the user in an installation?


These are usually auxiliary low-speed control signals for "sideband" management, such as running a serial interface for diagnostics. Since they're for "just in case" uses, their parameters are not as tightly controlled as the main wires .
